# Understanding CMSampleBuffer & didOutputSampleBuffer

Tags: objective-c, swift, avfoundation, pixel, cmsamplebufferref

I'm trying to understand how does `CMSampleBuffer` works. Eventually i'm looking for the most efficient way to change the `CMSampleBuffer` pixels (which are at `kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange` format), into `grayScale` pixels.

**The final result would be (fast)grayscale live video stream.**

I have tried the following :

```
 CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, kCVPixelBufferLock_ReadOnly);
    char *baseBuffer = (char *)CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer);
```

Which somehow suppose to indicate about the pixels. But from there i'm kind of lost. Any suggestions folks?

Comment: There is this method [CIImage imageWithCVPixelBuffer: imageBuffer] which gives you the CIImage to do the processing stuff (imageBuffer is your CVImageBufferRef)

Comment: @Xcoder Hey. Thank you for commenting! I'm aware of this type of approach, but i'm using openCV & dlib(C++ Libraries) , for future processing, and the only way to handle this kind of thing is thru the pixels(there are extra use-cases).

Comment: sorry man.my knowledge is limited to simple stuff on core image filtering. you can use this ans if it is of any help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5176209/what-is-the-best-fastest-way-to-convert-cmsamplebufferref-to-opencv-iplimage

Comment: @Xcoder Appreciate the help buddy, I did checked this answer , it helped but still much more to learn